# PATH related issues

Tags: terminal, path

A couple of days ago, I added code to my Mac's PATH to make some newly installed programs work properly on my machine. Unfortunately, it seems I have messed it up somewhere because some additional lines are printed every time I open my terminal.

Here is a screenshot of my terminal:

[image]

And here is a screenshot of my PATH Variable:

[image]

Does anyone know how I can remove extra lines in my terminal?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I renamed my **~/.zshrc** file to **~/.zshrc2**. Then all the extra lines were not shown anymore while opening up my terminal. Now I am sure the problems belong somewhere in my **~/.zshrc** file

You can rename a folder by entering this command `mv old-name-folder new-name-folder` in the folder's directory.